# UITableViewCell Reuse

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is reusing cells. Some of the cells in my table are a slightly different hight than others. When reusing the cell the table view seems to add the cell at the height it used to be, and then animate it to the new height. I don't want it to do this!

I have tries putting CATransactions around my layoutSubviews and prepareForReuse, which both do some layout, and disabling actions but this has not fixed the problem.

The cells are all pretty much the same, they just have a different amount of padding at the top and bottom depending on if they are at the top/bottom/in the middle somewhere.

Is there some nifty trick I am missing here?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Are you using different *reuseIdentifiers* for your different types of cells ? Like *@"smallCell"*, *@"largeCell"*, etc. ?

Comment: Currently, I'm not, I thought I would be able to reuse the cell without a problem but I may need to do it like that.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove your last edit. If you solved the problem by yourself, answer your own question and acccept your answer. You should not answer the question in the question itself. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, done. Won't let me accept it yet though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was to do with animating the insert of the row, not the reuse of cells. It would seem that using UITableViewRowAnimationNone still animates the insertion of the cell. By wrapping the call to insert cells in a CATransaction with actions disabled the problem is solved. :)

Sorry for the mix up!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a trick, but [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) will let the table view know what height the cells should be.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am indeed implementing this method.

Comment: Then you should post us your code for all tableview Datasource methods, so we can see what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to return the height for every row.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return 49;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am indeed implementing this method.